# %matplotlib inline magic ImportError

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Every time I run `%matplotlib inline` in my ipython notebook, I receive an `ImportError` telling me I have `No module named moves`. I've run `pip install moves` and that doesn't fix the problem. I've tried uninstalling `moves` and reinstalling/updating it, then uninstalling `six` and reinstalling/updating it (the module that contains `moves`), but nothing seems to work. I'm running `six 1.90`, `moves 0.1`, `ipython 2.3.1`, `matplotlib 1.4.3`, and `python 2.7.6`. Might I have some weird conflicting stuff when I'm loading the modules with the `inline` magic?

EDIT: here is the full error:

```
/Users/$USER/.virtualenv/$VIRTUALENVNAME/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/deepreload.pyc in load_next(mod, altmod, name, buf)  
    161  
    162     if result is None:  
--> 163         raise ImportError("No module named %.200s" % name)  
    164  
    165     return result, next, buf  

ImportError: No module named moves
```

Comment: Have you try to update you PYTHONPATH environment variable before launching ipython? For example (under Linux) try something like: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/some/path/to/movespkg

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately...I'm also using python within virtualenv if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behavior & resolved it by commenting out the following pieces of my `~/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` file.

```
c.InteractiveShell.deep_reload = True

c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
    'autoreload'
]
```